# prove this set is closed in Hilbert space

Tags: general-topology

Let X a Hilbert space admit a countable orthonormal basis $\{ e_i \} ^{\infty}_{i = 1} $
and set

> $ S= \{ \frac{i +1}{i} e_i \; : i \geq 1 \}$

Prove that $S$ is closed.

any suggestion would be helpful . thank you

Comment: If $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $Y\subset X$ such that $r=\inf \{d(u,v):u,v\in Y\land u\ne v\} >0$ then $Y$ is a closed discrete subspace of  $X.$ If $p\in X$   the open ball $B_d(p,r/2)$ contains at most one member of  $Y.$

Comment: excuse me but what is the set $Y$ ?

Comment: In your Q, let Y=S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125299/prove-that-a-set-consisting-of-a-sequence-and-its-limit-point-is-closed), it suffices to prove that $S$ has no limit points.

Suppose that there exists $\lim_k \frac{i_k+1}{i_k}e_{i_k}=f$, where $\{i_k\}_k$ is a strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers. Then $\lim_k e_{i_k}=f$, which implies $(f,e_j)=\lim_k (e_{i_k},e_j)=0$ for all $j$, so $f=0$, but $\Vert f\Vert=\lim_k\Vert e_{i_k}\Vert=1$, so we have a contradiction. Then $S$ has no limit points, as wanted.

Comment: First thank you for this cleaver proof, and correct my comment if it is wrong, "a set S is closed if $\forall  (x_n)$ sequence of $S$ converges to $x$ then $x$ should be in $S$. and you proved that if ther exists a sequence in $S$ that does not have any limit to converges to, then $S$ is closed !

Comment: @Myriam I used the fact that, if the convergent sequences of $S$ are the eventually constant ones, then $S$ is closed.  Notice that $\{(i_k+1)/i_k\cdot e_k\}_k$ is the form of any non-eventually constant sequence in $S$. I checked (by contradiction) that $\{(i_k+1)/i_k\cdot e_k\}_k$ has no limit point $f$, so the only convergent sequences of $S$ are the eventually constant ones, and therefore $S$ is closed by what I said at the beginning of the comment.